# use :has to take two element in attribute

Tags: javascript, css, sass, less

I have this HTML code:

```html
<button class="mod">
  <icon></icon>
  <span><span>
</button>
```

I need to separate icon and span only when the button has two children, something like this in CSS:

```css
.mod:has(+icon,+span) {
  padding-left: 1px;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use direct child combinator (`>`) plus
`:first-child` pseudo-class plus
sibling combinator (`+`)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

button {
  display: block;
}

.btn:has(> :first-child + *) {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
    </button>

    <button class="btn">
        <span>1</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, the OP is using `icon` as the first child, not `span`, and they wanted to detect both elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but he also said this "...when the button has two children..."
and that's why I made it this way to work when there are 2 childs no matter what they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple `:has()` selectors: `.mod:has(icon):has(span)`

Here's a working example:

```css
.mod {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.mod:has(icon):has(span) {
  padding-left: 1px;
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button class="mod">Lorem</button>
<button class="mod">  
  Ipsum
  <icon></icon>
  <span></span>
</button>
<button class="mod">Dolor</button>
```

Note that, as pointed out by @MisterJojo in the comments below, the `:has()` selector does not yet have full support amongst all major browsers. You can check which browsers do support it [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas), to validate that it covers your required user base.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/rSOVx90.png Which browser are you using? I'm guessing Firefox https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas

Comment: That's interesting that a Chromium-based browser has that issue. It seems that it's maybe not been updated to the latest runtime, as :`has()` is a relatively new addition.